# Groovy Doesn't print anything in File Maker?

Tags: groovy

I wrote groovy for connecting to FTP.
But it doesn't print anything 
please check it once.It doesn't shows any errors

```
    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

    start()

    def start()
    {
    def ftpClient = new FTPClient()
     ftpClient.connect("172.17.5.105")
     ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()
     println(ftpClient.replyString)
     ftpClient.login("FTPUser","Santosh@123")
     println(ftpClient.replyString)
      ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/")
     println(ftpClient.replyString)`enter code here`
     ftpClient.fileType=(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)
     println(ftpClient.replyString)`enter code here`

      def incomingFile = new File("D:\\FileMakerExamples\\Autoplus.txt")
      incomingFile.withOutputStream { ostream ->
       ftpClient.retrieveFile("Autoplus.txt", ostream )
      }
   println(ftpClient.replyString);
    ftpClient.disconnect()
      }
```

Comment: What is File Maker and how is it relevant (e.g. why not tag it).  If you use Groovy as the scripting language of another tool, this tool might just be bending stdout/err to something else and you are supposed to use some logging facility from that outside world.  Or another simple explanation, why this prints nothing is, that it never runs?

Comment: It seems that code is not getting executed